# Code with CGColorSpaceCreateDeviceRGB does not compile

Tags: ios, core-graphics

I'm trying to subclass UIButton and need to implement drawing gradient in drawRect: method. But calling any of CGColorSpaceCreateDeviceRGB(), CGColorGetComponents(), CGGradientCreateWithColorComponents() leads to a bunch of linker errors stating:

> **Apple Mach-O Linker (Id) Error**
>
> Undefined symbols for architecture i386:
>   "_CGColorSpaceCreateDeviceRGB", referenced from:
>         -[GradientButton drawRect:] in GradientButton.o

It seems like some header is missing, but searching through Quartz2D and CoreGraphics references still gave no result.

Comment: The header is not missing; if it were, your app wouldn't have compiled, and you wouldn't have gotten to the linking stage.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Did you link `CoreGraphics.framework` in your app?

It should look something like this:

[image]